# Required field Validation in WPF text box

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

I need a simple way to validate of text boxes (Required Field). It should check all mandatory field existence , when user press button.

I have tried this code :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="25" Text="*" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="62,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtEmail1" Text="" Height="61" Margin="116,10,194,0" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

please anyone suggest a way to make validation in Text boxes in WPF.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to a property of a view model and implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in the view model class.

Please refer to the following sample code.

**Code:**

```
public partial class Window3 : Window
{
    Window3ViewModel viewModel = new Window3ViewModel();
    public Window3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.Validate();
    }
}

public class Window3ViewModel : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void Validate()
    {
        bool isValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_text);
        bool contains = _validationErrors.ContainsKey(nameof(Text));
        if (!isValid && !contains)
            _validationErrors.Add(nameof(Text), "Mandatory field!");
        else if (isValid && contains)
            _validationErrors.Remove(nameof(Text));

        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
    }

    public bool HasErrors => _validationErrors.Count > 0;

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        string message;
        if (_validationErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out message))
            return new List<string> { message };

        return null;
    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window3" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="25" Text="*" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="62,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtEmail1" Text="{Binding Text}" Height="61" Margin="116,10,194,0" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And please refer to the following blog post for more information about how data validation in WPF works.

**Data validation in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

I will show you how you can validate data using IDataErrorInfo. This interface has only two members which need to be implemented:

public string Error { get; } - gets an error message indicating what is wrong with this object
public string this[string columnName] { get; } - get the error message for the property with the given name.
Once you implement the IDataErrorInfo you need to set the ValidatesOnDataErrors to true in the element that you want to validate. To simplify the code example, I implemented IDataErrorInfo in the MainViewModel as you can see below:

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }              

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = string.Empty;

            switch (columnName)
            {
                case nameof(FirstName):
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName))
                        error = "First name cannot be empty.";
                    if (FirstName?.Length > 50)
                        error = "The name must be less than 50 characters.";
                    break;

                case nameof(LastName):
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName))
                        error = "Last name cannot be empty.";
                    break;
            }

            return error;
        }
    }

    public string Error => string.Empty;
}
```

and in the **TextBox** element, I set **ValidatesOnDataError**s to **true**:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```